# Writing optimized multiple conditional statements Or use any other way to check condition? in python

Tags: python-3.x

What is the optimized way to write below conditional statements, i wanted to avoid the multiple if-elif statements

```
def test(val):
     return False if val is 0 else True

def test_func(x=None, y=None):
    if(x == "check" and y == "1" and test(0) == False):
        print("Option 1")
    elif(x == "check" and y == "2" and test(0) == False):
        print("Option 2")
    elif(x == "uncheck" and y == "1" and test(1) == True):
        print("Option 3")
    elif(x == "uncheck" and y == "2" and test(1) == True):
        print("Option 4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this:

```
if x == "check" and test(0) == False:
    if y == "1":
        print("Option 1")
    else:
        print("Option 2")
elif x == "uncheck" and test(1) == true:
    if y == "1":
        print("Option 3")
    else:
        print("Option 4")
```

I don't know if it helps because it isn't that shortened (If it doesn't please give me more context of what your trying to do so I can try a different approach), but I couldn't optimaze it more. *Hope this helps.*

-JLT

Comment: I was wondering something like "switch type/ dictionary mapping / map" ... can work in such scenario.

Comment: That could work, then you have to define these in the beginning of your program, I'll add a link under this comment. In just a minute.

Comment: I'm prerry new to python myself but you should be able to make your code better with dictionarys here is a link: https://youtu.be/ZEZdys-fHDw

Comment: If you can't figure it out from there, I'd recommend you check out the rest of the series

Comment: If my reply was helpfull you chould mark my answer as accepted so that people with the same problem can use this tread insted of posting a question